# Are Star Wars ship shields a bubble or skin tight?

Tags: star-wars

There seems some inconsistency with Star Wars shields. Personal/Planetary shields seems to be globe like as seen on CIS Droidika and the shield on the Death Star II or Scarif having shields that are projected in a globe around the object.

However starship shields seem to be skin tight, for example there are many shots of fighters making straffing runs on capital ships coming in tight and close with no issue and with dogfighting showing impacts closer to the hull and not on a 'globe' around the ship.

Is this just classic Star Wars poor explanation and continuity problems or is there an in-lore explanation for this?

Comment: The 'cannon fire' seems to explode on impact (illuminating the impacted shield area as well with an energy transfer). It doesn't slow its progress then bounce off.

Comment: It could also be different shield types.

Answer (score 1):

In *star Wars* they have both particle and ray shielding, particle shielding stops energy weapons while ray shielding stops physical objects. During the battle of scarrif an x-wing crashed into the shield like it was a solid object . Other times laser fire passes through and hits the starship, like in return of the jedi.

Comment: Yeah that´s what i meant

Comment: @T.J.L. I've taken the liberty of doing it for them.

Comment: Is there any way for you to back up these claims a little more?